# Unable to extract necessary information from my .txt file

Tags: numpy, dataset, text-files

> 0    .17    .29     d ih
> 1     .29    .73 k l ay n d
> 1     .73    .84     g ih

This is a sample of the .txt file that I am working on.

I have tried using the np.loadtxt() to extract the last column,

```
    syl_array = []
    try:
        fid = open(syl_file, 'r')
        syl_array = np.loadtxt(fid, usecols=(0, 1, 2, 3), dtype={'names': ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd'), 'formats': ('i4', 'f4', 'f4', 'U10')})
        fid.close
    except:
        print('File does not exist')
        return

    labels = syl_array['a']
    spurtStartTimes = syl_array['b']
    spurtEndTimes = syl_array['c']
    syllables = syl_array['d']
```

**This code gives the following output**,

--['d' 'k' 'g']--

---

**But the output I want is,**

--['d ih', 'k l ay n d', 'g ih']--

---

I want each group of syllables from the same row to be one element in the array. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the input file, an image is **not** reproducible

Comment: @mozway I have modified the question and provided the sample of the input file that I'm working on.

Comment: The question has been improved, but it would be more likely to attract answers with executable code that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over how the file itself is generated, what you are missing is a meaningful delimiter. The problem here is that there is no way for any standard parser to know that the space between `0` and `.17` means you want those values to be in different column, whereas the space between `d` and `ih` does NOT mean this.

If you replace the spaces that represent columns with delimiters other than space (i.e. comma or tab), you can get numpy to do what you want.

```python
"""
syl_file contents:
0\t.17\t.29\td ih
1\t.29\t.73\tk l ay n d
1\t.73\t.84\tg ih
"""
arr = np.loadtxt(
    syl_file,
    delimiter="\t",
    dtype=dict(
        names=('a','b','c','d'),
        formats=('i4','f4','f4','U10')
    )
)
print(arr)
"""
Output:
array(
    [
        (0, 0.17, 0.29, 'd ih'),
        (1, 0.29, 0.73, 'k l ay n d'),
        (1, 0.73, 0.84, 'g ih')
    ],
    dtype=[('a', '<i4'), ('b', '<f4'), ('c', '<f4'), ('d', '<U10')]
)
"""
```

However, if you truly have no control over how `syl_file` is generated, then you will need to write your own custom parser. Depending on how big the file is, you could write something as simple as:

```python
rows = []
with open("/tmp/tmp.txt") as f:
    for row in f.readlines():
        if row.strip() == "":
            continue
        parsed = row.split()
        parsed[0] = int(parsed[0])
        parsed[1:3] = map(float, parsed[1:3])
        parsed[3] = " ".join(parsed[3:]) # Combine the remaining columns into a single value
        rows.append(parsed[:4]) # Our result is in the first 4 columns!

arr = np.array(rows, dtype=object)
```